# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect all requests coming in to the web server as http://portal.company.com/legacy to http://portal.company.com/wps/portal/public/legacy/legacyportlet with the following rule, but it is not working as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal\.company\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/legacy$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wps/portal/public/legacy/legacyportlet$1 [NC,L,PT]
```

I have also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal\.company\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/legacy /wps/portal/public/legacy/legacyportlet [NC,L,PT]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like your source or target URLs change in any way, so possibly you're better off using Apache's basic [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) which just redirects one URL to another.

Comment: Yeah, the redirect is the way to go.  I had them try it earlier and it didn't work, but after looking in to it they were editing the wrong conf file.  :)

Comment: Smooth. I hope you didn't let them off too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^portal\.company\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^legacy/?$ /wps/portal/public/legacy/legacyportlet [NC,L]
```

**Remember** that in .htaccess RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash of URI.